# How to monitor the error log of a Java Applet running in a browser?

Tags: java, browser, error-handling, applet, console

I have written a Java applet that runs perfectly in the applet viewer but when I try to run it in the browser it will not initialize, instead I'm stuck at the gray screen of death.

```
<html><body>
<applet code=main.Main.class
    width=800 height=600>
</applet></body></html>
```

Java File main/Main.java

```
package main;

//etc some imports here

public class Main extends JApplet implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void init() {
       // do some stuff here
    }

    //.......
}
```

I have also tried running some simple applets in the browser and they work, so I do not know why doesn't this one work.

Is there any way I can monitor the error log from the browser? So I might see where does this applet fails?

Comment: Have you tried starting the browser from command line and checking for any error output?

Comment: every browser has a way to open the JVM console output so it should be there..

Comment: OMG! thank you NoBugs... such a simple solution, apparently i have some imports from class path that are not found. How come i didn't though of it

Comment: @Jack: I think that some smaller browsers don't have a JVM console, and they do this as a conscious decision to keep the code base small. I think that this applies to Opera and maybe Chrome.

Comment: This does not mean that when debugging such things using an heavier browser with a consolse support should be avoided. Otherwise we could just test code always with `-O2` :)

Comment: Please post your solution as a separate answer and self-accept it

Comment: Don't write `Solved - Solution found thanks to NoBugs.` into your question. The system will not mark a comment as accepted answer, so people, searching for the same question will not know it is solved by viewing at the colored `solution accepted` identifier. Animate @NoBugs to repeat his comment as answer instead.

Comment: ohh, sorry, i'm new here, i'll make answer my question :) thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the browser in the console will display all the errors

Apparently an external jar was not included in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Start your applet in the **appletviewer**, or start the browser from the shell, to read the error messages.